vscode devcontainer permission error - failed to create directory `/workspaces/main/target/debug/.fingerprint
This seems like an old issue but still unresolved.
These are the previous references here and here.
My environment:

Host OS: Ubuntu 22.04 VScode version: Version: 1.93.0 Commit:
4849ca9bdf9666755eb463db297b69e5385090e3 Date:
2024-09-04T13:02:38.431Z Electron: 30.4.0 ElectronBuildId: 10073054
Chromium: 124.0.6367.243 Node.js: 20.15.1 V8: 12.4.254.20-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 6.8.0-40-generic

I have been facing this too often, making in unviable to use devcontainers.  Considering to switch to some other alternative.  May be perhaps I should just create a docker-compose file on the host and run it myself and have everything installed there, instead of relying on an unstable and much hyped devcontainer?
